# Confusion matrix of autoencoder shows more failure occurrences (FN+TP) than the actual failure occurrences in the entire dataset

Tags: tensorflow, autoencoder, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to implement extreme rare event prediction using autoencoder with the help of this [code](https://towardsdatascience.com/extreme-rare-event-classification-using-autoencoders-in-keras-a565b386f098). I'm using my own data (severely unbalanced data) where there are only 6 failure events. The confusion matrix that I get is as follows:

[image: confusion matrix]

It shows that my autoencoder model is able to predict **three** of the **15** (FN+TP) true failure events. However, there are only **six** failure events in the entire dataset. How come the confusion matrix contains **15** true failure events?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: can you add how you go about generating/processing the data and training your model
It could for example stem from you using kfold validation but i think more info is necessary

Comment: @john Generating/processing the data and training model is done as explained [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/extreme-rare-event-classification-using-autoencoders-in-keras-a565b386f098)

Comment: is it possible to share your data set? The code itself should not predict more than the instances as far as i can tell

Comment: @john the data set consists of several columns, the first column for timestamp, the last column for failure indication (either o or 1) and the other columns are sensors data. Apart from the model in the   [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/extreme-rare-event-classification-using-autoencoders-in-keras-a565b386f098), I've changed the batch size, learning rate, and the complexity of the dense layers. If I increase the `shift_by` value, (FN+TP) increases accordingly.